# Android - compare app version number between my app and google play market

Tags: android

I am currently using Android version name as version number and use the following way to get the app version  number

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.android.myApp"
  android:versionCode="12"
  android:versionName="1.2.37">
```

code:

```
try {
    PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
    PackageInfo info = manager.getPackageInfo("org.moo.android.myApp", 0);
    int code = info.versionCode;
    String name = info.versionName;

    // Compare with values on the server to see if there is a new version
} catch(NameNotFoundException nnf) {
    nnf.printStackTrace();
}
```

But my version uploaded to the google play is 1.2.39

How can I get the google play app version 1.2.39 and thence initiate the end device users to download the apk of the latest verion?

Comment: AFAIK.If there is updated version on playstore the end user will get notify to download latest one automatically(by googleplay). You do not need to do anything.

Comment: Just let Google Play handle this for you. Don't over-complicated your app unnecessarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Play Services don't expose such API which returns current published version although you can create your own API to show pop up to update the app.